# Sed Command Not Writing Changes to SQL file

Tags: database

I am setting up a new dev environment using a wp multisite as my base with all my plugins & themes, then setting up to export any subsite to single as I will need.

Exporting the subsite with wp-cli has been simple enough:

```
wp db export --tables=$(wp db tables --url=subsite.mainsite.com --format=csv --skip-plugins --skip-themes --allow-root) /var/www/html/mainsite.com/dumps/subsitedb.sql --allow-root
```

However I trying to minimize the time needed to change the table prefixes and the urls using sed commands:

`sed "s#wpb_2_:#wp_#g" subsitedb.sql`

and

`sed 's|subsite\.example\.com|\.newdomain\.com|g' subsitedb.sql`

respectively.

Oddly enough, both commands appear to execute without error, however when I perform a quick search of the db using `nano subsitedb.sql`  no changes have actually been written to the database.  Both table prefix and original subiste url are unchanged.

What am I missing?
Thanks

I know that this may be more a linux command question rather than wordpress question.  I am asking in this group of the wordpress serialized db content that has to be accounted for when using sed commands.

Comment: note that this will have the same issues that a naive search replace SQL query has, by changing the length you will corrupt and mangle any serialised PHP, and it will no longer be possible to deserialise it, causing fatal errors and other problems when WP loads.

Comment: I've changed the title to better reflect the actual question, but as I said, a `.sql` file is not a database. You should have asked this on stackoverflow as this has nothing to do with WordPress, it's a `sed` file modification question. `.sql` files are just text files with SQL queries that can be ran to reproduce tables/rows and their contents when imported into a database

Comment: it seems like you're trying to do a migration and want to avoid downtime where the database is importing and you haven't changed the URL yet, but instead you keep devising solutions and asking about those instead. Why not ask about the actual problem instead of asking how to fix your solution? You're falling into the X Y Problem trap, it would be much easier and faster if you asked about your problem instead of asking about the solutions you've thought up. Use them as examples in your question, don't make them the question itself

Comment: @TomJNowell fair enough, I will take your advice.